# Suggestions on distributing python data/code over worker nodes?

Tags: python, hadoop, twisted, distributed, celery

I'm starting to venture into distributed code and am having trouble figuring out which solution fits my needs based on all the stuff out there.  Basically I have a python list of data that I need to process with a single function.  This function has a few nested for loops but doesn't take too long(about a min) for each item on the list.  My problem is the list is very large(3000+ items).  I'm looking at multiprocessing but I think I want to experiment with multi-server processing it(because ideally, if the data gets larger I want to be able to have the choice of adding more servers during the job to make it run quicker).

I basically looking for something that I can distribute this data list through(and not super needed but it would be nice if I could distribute my code base through this also)

So my question is, what package can I use to achieve this?  My database is hbase so I already have hadoop running(never used hadoop though, just using it for the database).  I looked at celery and twisted as well but I'm confused on which will fit my needs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend [celery](http://celeryproject.org/). You can define a task that operates on a single item of your list:

```
from celery.task import task
@task
def process(i):
    # do something with i
    i += 1
    # return a result
    return i
```

You can easily parallelize a list like this:

```
results = []
todo = [1,2,3,4,5]
for arg in todo:
    res = process.apply_async(args=(arg))
    results.append(res)

all_results = [res.get() for res in results]
```

This is easily scalable by just adding more celery workers.

Answer (score 2):

check out [rabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Python bindings are available through [pika](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika). start with a simple [work_queue](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) and run few [rpc calls](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html).

It may look troublesome to experiment distributed computing in python with an external engine like rabbitMQ (there's a small learning curve for installing and configuring the rabbit) but you may find it even more useful later.

... and celery can work hand-in-hand with rabbitMQ, checkout [robert pogorzelski's tutorial](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2272371/rabbitmq-celery-and-django.pdf)  and [Simple distributed tasks with Celery and RabbitMQ](http://www.sammyliu.com/2011/06/23/celery-simple-distributed-tasks-with-celery-and-rabbitmq)